# Why is XmlReader appending namespace uris to each element?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlreader, xmlserializer

I've got a Stream containing xml in the following format that I want to deserialize into C# objects

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OrganisationMetaData xmlns="urn:organisationMetaDataSchema">
   <Organisations>
     <Organisation>
       <Code>XXX</Code>
       <Name>Yyyyyy</Name>...
```

I've done this loads of times with strings, but with the stream it is kindly appending the namespace attribute to all the complex elements. If I just remove the xmlns attribute, and forget about validating it against a schema, it just appends an empty xmlns attribute. The problem I have is that the Deserialize method in XmlSerializer (?), throws an error saying it doesn't expect the attribute. I have tried decorating the class with the XmlRoot and XmlType attributes but this didn't change anything.

Here's the class I want to deserialize into

```
[XmlRoot(
   ElementName = "OrganisationMetaData", 
   Namespace = "urn:organisationMetaDataSchema")]
public class OrganisationMetaData
{
    public List<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(
   TypeName = "Organisation", 
   Namespace = "urn:organisationMetaDataSchema")]
public class Organisation
{
   public string Code {get; set;}

   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Here's the method that is being used to do the work

```
 public IList<Organisation> DeserializeOrganisations(Stream stream)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrganisationMetaData));

        var mappingAssembly = //Resource in another assembly

        var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(
            "urn:organisationMetaDataSchema",
            XmlReader.Create(
                mappingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                    // An xml schema
                    )
                )
            );
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
                           {
                               ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
                               Schemas = schemas,
                               ValidationFlags =
                     XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
                           };            

        settings.ValidationEventHandler += settings_ValidationEventHandler;
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

        var metaData= (OrganisationMetaData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return metaData.Organisations.ToList();
    }
```

I've tried this using DataContractSerializer but that brings it's own oppotunities to learn, so if anyone could help with what I ought to be putting in the attributes to get XmlSerializer to work, it would be great.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the code to use data contract serializer, it gave me more obvious errors around namespace that allowed me to have a reader that validated the xml stream against the schema, and then rewind the stream and use it again in another reader that deserialized the xml.

Reading [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1651010) alerted me to a gotcha where xml elements are required to be in alphabetical order. I also found that when deserializing a property of my class that was an enum, I need to require this to be present (it is not nullable after all).

This then caused another error where I had an xml node with some values omitted (ok by my schema), however the data contract expected these to be in sequence so I had to specify this explicitly.

I ended up with a data member attribute like this

```
[DataMember(
        Name = "MyEnumType", 
        EmitDefaultValue = false, 
        IsRequired = true, 
        Order = 3)] 
//Just assume I added this prop after my Code, and Name properties from above
```

Thanks to Marc for taking time to look at this.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the `[XmlRoot]` can only be applied to a root type such as a class; if you are using a `List<>` as the root it won't work - but we can shim that with `[XmlElement]`. I'm using the `Stream` approach (via `Encoding.UTF8`), but note that this isn't really the heart of the issue IMO (the root type is):

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="urn:organisationMetaDataSchema")]
public class Organisations
{
    private readonly List<Organisation> items = new List<Organisation>();
    [XmlElement("Organisation")]
    public List<Organisation> Items { get { return items; } }

}
public class Organisation
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?><Organisations xmlns='urn:organisationMetaDataSchema'><Organisation><Code>XXXX</Code><Name>YYYYYYYY</Name></Organisation></Organisations>";
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Organisations));
        using (Stream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            Organisations orgs = (Organisations)ser.Deserialize(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm having a bit of brain fade on this now. My xml doesn't have the single quotes that your string has. How would you overcome this, something as simple as Replace(...) ?

Comment: I've tried just about all I can think of here, so after about 8 hours, I've given up and gone for DataContractSerializer instead, which at east can tell me a bit more about what it doesn't like about the xml. Thanks for your help Marc :)

Comment: @Mark - the single quote doesn't matter. The code as posted should deserialize the xml you have cited. Can you post (or e-mail if you like) your classes at all? I'm pretty sure I can tell you what is wrong...

Comment: I've got a few constraints here wrt. posting the code out, but i'll cobble something together just to get a decent answer to this. The problem I found was that if I got my stream into a string it had escape characters before the double quotes, newlines, and returns. I have no idea where these came from. I've moved on to using DataContractSerializer, but this has a problem with the Organisations object, even if I wrapped it in another object.

Comment: I've switched over to DataContractSerializer, it might help me out longer term too, after finding this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651010 ), I got it working nicely. If you want to continue with the issue with XmlSerializer and you need anything from me please let me know. Cheers